# How to force MWI for an endpoint via API

Tags: sip, freeswitch

Is it possible to set the MWI for a registered endpoint in Freeswitch through the WebAPI?

If so, what would the command be?

Answer (score 0):

You can just fire a `mwi` event which will cause freeswitch to send a MWI to the phone, it can be done easily from lua api, something like http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/lua?lua/api.lua and in api.lua file (which you put inn the freeswitch scripts directory) you would add the code to fire the MWI event.

Some examples for the lua code:

1. From [Freeswitch](https://freeswitch.org/stash/projects/FS/repos/freeswitch/browse/scripts/lua/mwi_event.lua);

   ```
   local event = freeswitch.Event("message_waiting");
   event:addHeader("MWI-Messages-Waiting", "no");
   event:addHeader("MWI-Message-Account", "sip:1000@10.0.1.100");
   -- event:addHeader("Sofia-Profile", "internal");
   event:fire();
   ```

Comment: Hey there. Please include some minimal code from your links to express what you mean. If ever those links break, your answer won't keep a high value.